# Sly.js carousel failing to execute in Safari or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bigcommerce

Implemented a slider with sly.js for the following site:

http://www.bangsshoes.com/home-test/

Working as expected in Firefox, but behaving strangely in Safari. Something is causing the js not to execute at the proper time which breaks the whole slider and looks terrible.

I changed it to fire on $(window).load vs $(document).ready which worked, but looks too jenky to the client, so I'm having to go back to the drawing board.

I believe this was working before at some point -- we switched to a static image for a few months. Since we switched back this week, it's broken.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: numberOfCartItemsArray is not returning null, you may want to fix that. I would suggest using some kind of debugger, like Visual Studio, Aptana or the Chrome Debugger itself.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. This is the issue. Unfortunately I'm not able to change the script so I'll have to contact their support. Thanks!